# Project Server In premise 2016 CSOM code with Claim based Authentication

Tags: csom

One of our clients has enabled ADFS on his Project server 2016 In premise environment .  We are using CSOM operation in our custom application and CSOM operations have failed due to this change.

For ADFS Claims based authentication we need to pass Authenticated cookie . Can someone help us with how to add authenticated Cookie with CSOM code.

Existing CSOM Code for getting list of projects:

```
public static void GetProjectListInpremise()
        {
            NetworkCredential net = null;

            Console.WriteLine("Read Project Online Started ..");
            string PWAOnlineUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings     ["pwaInpremiseUrl"];
            string userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pwaInpremiseUser"];
            string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pwaInpremiseUserPwd"];
            string domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pwaInpremiseDomian"];
            net = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);

            ProjectContext projContext = null;
            projContext = new ProjectContext(PWAOnlineUrl);
           // projContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.FormsAuthentication;
            projContext.Credentials = net;
            projContext.Load(projContext.Projects);
            projContext.ExecuteQuery();

            Console.WriteLine("Read Project Execute Query Successful..");

            foreach (PublishedProject pubProj in projContext.Projects)

            {

                Console.WriteLine("Project Name :" + pubProj.Name);

            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```